# Showing $m(r)=\int_0^{2 \pi} f(re^{i \theta}) d \theta$ is constant

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $A=\{z \in \mathbb{C}: 0<|z|<1 \},$, and suppose that $f:A \to \mathbb{C}$ is analytic on $A$. For $0<r<1$, define $$m(r)=\int_0^{2 \pi} f(re^{i \theta}) d \theta$$ Show that $m(r)$ is constant ont he interval $0<r<1$.

My approach:

Letting $z=re^{i\theta}$,

$$m(r)=\frac {1}{ir}\int_{|z|<1}\frac{f(z)}{z}dz=\frac{1}{ir}*2 \pi i*Res(f/z,0)=\frac{1}{r}*2\pi*f(0)$$ which is constant from $0<r<1$.

Right approach?

Comment: Right approach, but $\operatorname{Res}(f,0)$ is wrong, it's $\operatorname{Res}\left(\frac{f(z)}{z},0\right)$. And the $\frac{1}{r}$ is very wrong. $d\theta = \frac{dz}{iz}$.

Comment: Oops I meant to say that. So what I do with my $r$?

Comment: Wouldn't that follow from the mean value property of holomorphic functions

Comment: The $r$ is simply wrong, delete it. With $z=re^{i\theta}$, you have $dz = izd\theta$.

Comment: Ah i see! I treated it as a constant. And what do you know: Fisher and Amr the two complex analysis Gods commenting on my question. Thanks both of you @Amr

Comment: @DanielFischer I didn't know we can just neglect it.

Comment: You can't neglect it. Your introduction of the $1/r$ was erroneous. $$\int_{\lvert z\rvert = r} \frac{f(z)}{z}\,dz = \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{f(re^{i\theta})}{re^{i\theta}} (ire^{i\theta})\,d\theta.$$ The $r$'s cancel.

Comment: I am certainly not a complex analysis god :)